# When is a solution $P(f'(x)) = Q(f(x))$ periodic or double periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, elliptic-functions

Consider the differential equation

$$P(f '(x)) = Q(f(x))$$

Where $P(x),Q(x)$ are polynomials.

Examples are $f'(x) = 1 + f(x)^2$ where we get a tan solution and $f'(x)^2 = 4 f(x)^3 - g_2 f(x) - g_3$ where we get a Weierstrass elliptic function solution.
One of them is periodic , the other double periodic.

In general, When is a solution $P(f'(x)) = Q(f(x))$ periodic or double periodic ?

I looked at some famous elliptic functions and most of them are defined with 2 or 3 functions like the Dixon elliptic functions with $cm'(x) = - sm^2(x),sm'(x) = cm^2(x)$ what is related to the Fermat curve $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ and the Eisenstein integers. Or the lemniscate elliptic functions with $sl'(x) = (1+ sl^2(x)) cl(x) , cl'(x) = -(1 + cl^2(x)) sl(x)$. However the lemniscate elliptic function $sl$ also satisfies a selfreference one : $(sl'(x))^2 = 1 - sl(x)^4$ thereby satifying the type of differential equation I was looking for.

It is basically just that solving

$$P(x) + Q(y) = 1$$

for $x$ or $y$ results in at least one function that satisfies :

$$P(f '(x)) = Q(f(x))$$

with the right initial conditions.

Usually what I find is that the degrees of $P$ and $Q$ are between $2$ and $4$.

So, what is going on ?

Does every pair of polynomials $P,Q$ with degrees between $2$ and $4$ give double periodic functions ?
Are degrees above $4$ possible to get double periodic functions ?

And when do we get periodic functions that are not double periodic ?

Does the Fermat curve

$$x^5 + y^5 = 1 $$

or

$$x^7 + y^7 = 1$$

and their related differential equations give us double periodic functions ?

I want to point out that a function of a periodic function is also periodic and the same applies to the double periodic case.

Also we get the trivial case for a polynomial $M(x)$ :

$$ M(P(f'(x))) = M(Q(f(x)))$$

which has as its solutions the same function $f$ as if $M$ was the identity function.

What basicly is an answer to my question of bounded degree, but I am looking for more insightful and general results ofcourse.

Some ideas I had were plugging in a fourier series with variable coefficients.
But I was dealing with infinitely many variables and not sure if my fourier series was even valid ; was it still analytic and did it still agree with the function it was describing ??
Another ideas was an analogue for fourier series, a series expansion for double periodic functions.
But I got stuck there too.
Not sure if that was going in the right direction or not.
Even if that works, I want to prove it does.

I tried some (complex analysis and geometric function theory ) theorems but they had problems with the poles and analytic continuation around those.
The taylor radius was too small and fourier requires $L^2$ spaces anyways.
I might be able to solve a specific case but I want the general idea.

I am ofcourse slightly aware of some basic results such as relating the period(if it exists) with some coefficients ( such as $g_2,g_3$ in the Weierstrass case ) and rewriting the equations as an integral. Or writing functions in terms of eachother. Or some infinite sums.
But that does not give me the insight I seek.

I am not an expert at the addition formula's but I also understand that an addition formula implies periodic or double periodic.
But again that does not give me what I seek.

How to look at this ?

Comment: Just a comment, in some cases the differential equation has a rational solution. As example is Weierstrass with $g_2 = g_3 = 0$, then we get $(x+c)^{-2}$ what is not periodic ofcourse. Also insightful ( I have no proof though ) is that every double periodic function is a rational function of $W(x),W'(x)$ where these are the Weierstrass and its derivative (with the same periods ofcourse). I do not know how to construct them though. And that result is a bit backward ; if I do not know the function is double periodic or a rational of those 2, I am stuck. Insightful but insufficient.

Comment: I have an idea ...

Comment: I conjecture that if $P(x) + Q(y)$ is irreducible ( does not factor ), and the solution associated with the curve $P(x) + Q(y) = 1$ is double periodic and meromorphic everywhere , then either $P(x)$ or $Q(y)$ is of degree $2$.